Optimal bulk insert to clickhouse
I have a large dataset containing over 10 million JSON records. Could someone please advise on the most efficient method to insert these into a string column table? Currently, I am using clickhouse_driver, but it takes approximately one minute to load 100,000 records.
current steps:

read data from db (each row as json)
load into dataframe
use insert_dataframe or execute method to insert into clickhouse table (target will just have one column with json rows)

code:
from clickhouse_driver import Client
client = Client(host,user, password,database)

for chunk in pd.read_sql(src_sql, conn1,chunksize=300000):              
df=pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=bq_column_names)
df_list=df['JsonData'].tolist()

bulk_insert_data = [(item,1)
                        for item in df_list
                        ]
        
client.execute("INSERT INTO schema.table (JsonData,batchseq) SETTINGS async_insert=1, wait_for_async_insert=1 VALUES", bulk_insert_data)


share your code, otherwise any feedback would be guesswork/supposition, check out [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

added the code for reading from dataframe and loading into clkhouse table, also the link seems to be not working

async_insert is not for bulk inserts it's for a lot of small inserts
most time your code just converts pandas df into list
look to
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/python#client-insert-method
insert method
and insert_df=true parameter

You can use the client.insert_df which efficiently performs bulk insertions.
An improvement in the data prepping to set the batchseq using vectorization.

prepped_df = df['JsonData']
prepped_df['batchseq'] = 1
  
client.insert_df(
    table='table',
    df=prepped_df, 
    database='schema',
    column_names=['JsonData','batchseq'])

